# How can I get xtabs to calculate means instead of sums in R?

Tags: r, average, mean

I have a data frame where each line represents an individual. That data frame has two variables: age and year. I want to make a table of average ages per year. How can I do it?

The best I could come up with was `xtabs(age ~ year, dataframe)`, but this gives me the sum of ages per year.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `aggregate`:

```
xtabs(hp~cyl+gear,aggregate(hp~cyl+gear,mtcars,mean))
   gear
cyl        3        4        5
  4  97.0000  76.0000 102.0000
  6 107.5000 116.5000 175.0000
  8 194.1667   0.0000 299.5000
```

Comment: Perfect! And quite an elegant solution, I must add. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the plyr package, specifically `ddply`

```
ddply(dataframe, .(year), summarise, mean(age))
```

If you have to use xtabs... see the above answer.

Comment: Thank you for showing me another very elegant solution, but since my actual problem involves three variables, I'm still going with stabs. :)

Comment: you can continue to list variables in ddply as well `ddply(dataframe, .(year), summarise, mean(age), max(height), sd(weight), etc...)`

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad that `xtabs` solution works for you. I must have a package loaded that interferes with it for me (and gives an error). Another solution would be:

```
tapply(dfrm$age, dfrm$year, FUN=mean)
```

To get additional dimensions to the table (array) just keep adding additional factors to the second INDEX argument in the form `list(fac1, fac2, fac3)`.

Applied to the example using mtcars:

```
 tapply(mtcars$hp, list(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$gear), mean)
         3     4     5
4  97.0000  76.0 102.0
6 107.5000 116.5 175.0
8 194.1667    NA 299.5
```

Or even more compactly:

```
with(mtcars, tapply(hp, list(cyl, gear), mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use 2 xtabs functions, first one to calculate the sum of the ages, 2nd one to get the headcount for each group, then get the mean by sum/headcount.

E.g., 
xtabs(age ~ year, dataframe)/xtabs( ~ year, dataframe)

However, the aggregate approach can be used to calculate median or other functions applied to the dataframe. Definitely more flexible.