# R Crosstab Based on Three Columns

Tags: r

Im not sure which functions to use or what to call it but given the data:
[image: Data Frame]

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    Name = sample(c("John", "Jill"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    Type = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    Rating = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I would like:

```
| Name | A | B  | C |
|------|---|----|---|
| Jill | 1 | 2  | 6 |
|------|---|----|---|
| John | 6 | 12 | 1 |
```

Where the columns are `Type`, the rows are `Name` and the data inside is the sum of `Rating`.

What is this called and how do I do it?

Comment: Try with `xtabs(Rating ~ Name + Type, df)` or `dcast(df, Name ~ Type, value.var = 'Rating')`

Comment: Awesome! I am not familiar with formula interface, is there a way to apply a different function than sum? For example is there a syntax for `xtabs(mean(Rating) ~ Name + Type, df)`?

Comment: Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007800/11154257 ). Thanks for your help